# Func<> and Action<> can't be found

Tags: .net, delegates

I have a delegate:

```
    delegate ResultType Caller<ResultType>(IPtxLogic logic);
```

Here is a function:

```
private ResultType ExecuteLogicMethod2<ResultType>(string sessionId,
    Caller<ResultType> action) 
    where ResultType : IResult, new()
    {...}
```

I want to replace the function signature with something like this:

```
private ResultType ExecuteLogicMethod2<ResultType>(string sessionId,
    Action<IPtxLogic, ResultType> action)
    where ResultType : IResult, new()
    {...}
```

Compiler tells me:

> Using the generic type 'System.Action' requires '1' type arguments

Why? How can I get access to 'standard' .NET class?

Thank you. Any thought are welcome.

P.S. I've created my custom delegate to resolve issue, but ... I don't want to create custom delegate for each of my 'custom action'...

```
delegate ResultType Action<ParameterType, ResultType>(ParameterType param);
```

P.P.S. I am using .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

leppie, your original thought was right:

1. I need to add 'System.Core' assembly into project!
2. I need to use Func<> // but this is not a core of the problem

Thanks.

These types are included into 3.5 out-of-the-box:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx

> Version Information
>   .NET Framework
>   Supported in: 4, 3.5

Answer (score 4):

<strike>Make sure you reference `System.Core.dll` and `using System.Linq;`</strike>

On second thought. You are using `Action` in place of `Func`.

You need `Func<IPtxLogic, ResultType>`.

Comment: `Action` and `Func` are in the `System` namespace. However the OP's error message suggests they've got `using System;` but are missing a reference to _System.Core.dll_.

Comment: @Tim Robinson: Nope, it was not THAT  :)